# Convert SQL Server 2008 query to bcp query

Tags: sql-server, r, bcp

I have a query that I'm using to create an input file for another program.  I'm trying to do the process using the bcp utility via an R script using the system command.  The query is as follows (using SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
case when [click] = 1 then 1
else -1
end  
+  ' ' 
+ '|'
+ 'hr ' hour
, C1
from [mydb].[dbo].[table1]
```

When I try to run the following in CMD things are fine :

```
C:\Users\me>bcp "SELECT top 1000 case when click = 1 then 1 else -1 end, + ' |hr ' hour, C1 from [mydb].[dbo].[table1]" queryout "C:\\Users\
\me\\Desktop\\bcp_test.txt" -T -c -t
```

However when I take this and try to run it in R using:

```
system('bcp "SELECT top 1000 case when click = 1 then 1 else -1 end, + ' |hr ' hour, C1 from [mydb].[dbo].[table1]" queryout "C:\\Users\
    \me\\Desktop\\bcp_test.txt" -T -c -t')
```

I get errors about string constants and Status 1 messages.  Anything seem off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a few issues:

- You are concatenating strings with numbers (i.e. the `CASE` returns a number but then it is being concatenated with other stuff)
- You have an extraneous comma just after the `END` of the `CASE` statement
- And I don't know how R escapes embedded quotes, but your main problem is in the concatenation of `+ ' |hr'`

Assuming that R uses a back-slash to escape embedded single-quotes, the command should be:

```
system('bcp "SELECT TOP 1000 CASE WHEN [click] = 1 then \'1\' else \'-1\' END + \' |hr \' AS [hour], [C1] FROM [mydb].[dbo].[table1];" queryout "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\bcp_test.txt" -T -c -t')
```

Comment: R uses backslashes as escape-character so to get one actual backslash screechOwl will need two (or four when there needs to be doubled-backslash) in the directory string.